# How to Find Specific file from various C folders using vb.net code

Tags: vb.net

```
Option Explicit On
Imports excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim objExcelApplication As New excel.Application
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As excel.Workbook
    Dim aname As String
    Dim bname As String
    Dim cname As String

    Dim directory = "C:\Project\"
    For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.xlsm", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim fname As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)
        aname = TextBox1.Text
        bname = "-001"
        cname = aname & bname
        If fname = cname & ".xlsm" Then
            objExcelWorkbook = objExcelApplication.Workbooks.Open(fname)
        End If
    Next

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Include what attempts you have made to solve the problem, ideally with some code, and people will be a lot more willing to assist.

Comment: I tried the only missing or get confused on code for search file by looking various folders

Comment: Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim fname As String
        Dim fpath As String
        Dim sname As String
        Dim aname As String
        Dim path As String
        sname = "-001"
        fname = TextBox1.Text
        fpath = "C:\Project\\"
        aname = fname & sname
        path = fpath & aname
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path & ".xlsm") Then
            MsgBox("File found.")
        Else
            MsgBox("File not found.")
        End If
         
    End Sub

End Class

Comment: Edit your question to include the code. It will be easier to read than it is in a comment.

Comment: Re above code when it runs at the end it gives comment that "Additional information: 'C9256-001.xlsm' could not be found. Check the spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is correct". However the file is there but it will not open it. can someone help for the code

Comment: @NILESHDESAI You haven't given a full path for the file to open.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your question in it. I'm surprised the Code Nanny at SO allowed this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim objExcelApplication As New excel.Application
    Dim objExcelWorkbook As excel.Workbook
    Dim directory = "C:\Project\"
    For Each filename As String In IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.xlsm", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        Dim fname As String = IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)
        If fname = TextBox1.Text & "-001" & ".xlsm" Then
            ' Since the filename already contains the full path: 
            objExcelWorkbook = objExcelApplication.Workbooks.Open(filename)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

1. No need for `aname`, `bname` and `cname`, since you only use them to build the file name to compare with `fname`.
2. you try to open the file based only on it's file name, and not on it's full path. since you already have the full file name (including it's path) in the variable named `filename`, just use it to open the excel workbook.